# HTML Basic question but I am scratching my head as I think it's right

Tags: html, css

I have two functions below.

- function ingredientsHover() <- When mouse hovers over 'ingredients icon', font goes to 300%
- function ingredientsNormal() <- font goes to 100% when mouse not there
- function preperationHover() <- When mouse hovers over 'preparation icon', font goes to 300%
- function preparationNormal() <- font goes to 100% when mouse not there

However, the error messages im getting are:

> error 1: Did you create your preparationNormal() function? Check your spelling and make sure you added the curly braces {}.

> error 2: Did you set the preparation Font Awesome font icon size inside the body of the preparationHover() function.

```js
function ingredientsHover() {
  document.getElementById("ingredients").firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = "300%";
}

function ingredientsNormal() {
  document.getElementById("ingredients").firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = "100%";
}

function preperationHover() {
  document.getElementById("preparation").firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = "300%";
}

function preparationNormal() {
  document.getElementById("preparation").firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = "100%";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>How to make Tea</h1>
    <img src="https://codeinstitute.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/5DCC/images/Content/oSVKMED.jpg" alt="A man drinking tea">
    <p>At the very least, tea is a flavourful way of getting enough fluid into your body each day. On top of that, studies have shown teas can help protect your teeth and your heart</p>
  </header>
  <section id="ingredients" onmouseover="ingredientsHover()" onmouseout="ingredientsNormal()">
    <!-- add a fontawesome icon here -->
    <h2>ingredients
      <i id="ingredients" class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Tea Bag</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Milk - Dairy/Plant based(Optional)</li>
      <li>Sugar/Honey (Optional)</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section id="preparation" onmouseover="preparationHover()" onmouseout="preparationNormal()">
    <!-- add a fontawesome icon here -->
    <h2>preparation <i id="preparation" class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
    <ol>
      <li>
        Run the tap a little so the water's nicely aerated, and only boil it once to keep the oxygen level up. Oxygen in water helps flavour!
      </li>
      <li>
        Pop a tea bag into your mug (<em>always</em> a big mug)
      </li>
      <li>
        Pour the hot water over the tea bag and stir briefly.
      </li>
      <li>
        Tea needs time to unlock all its flavour, so give it 3-4 minutes to do its thing. This is a perfect time to grab a sneaky cookie or daydream about vacations.
      </li>
      <li>
        Before removing the tea bag, gently squish it with a spoon against the side of the mug. Not too much or you'll make it bitter.
      </li>
      <li>
        If you want, throw in some milk or sugar or honey or nothing else at all.
      </li>
      <li>
        Enjoy!
      </li>
    </ol>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>Copyright Me 2020</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Codepen, for those who wish to fork and play: https://codepen.io/zethzeth/pen/XWeZKqg

Comment: @Zeth Or just use the `[<>]` stacksnippet I just made

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - I made one for you and it gives a VERY clear message

Comment: You also have duplicate IDs. Remove the ID from the section and have this css: `#preparation:hover { transform: scale(1.5); color:red }`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your script code. `preparationHover` in your HTML while `preperationHover` in your javascript.

btw I suggest you to use CSS `:hover` to change their font-size.

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions. They need to be deleted by the asker